# PNG textures get messed up when switching to cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

[image: How the colour textures show up in cycles]

[image: How it looks in cycles]

When I tried rendering my scene in cycles, I noticed my materials where all messed up. To test it, I directly connected up my image textures to the material output nodes, and this is how it ended up. This at least means it isn't about a node not being supported in cycles. The textures where converted from .dds to .png using an external program, and they only break in sRGB. In non-colour, while bleaker, they do look okay in cycles.
What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to the PNG world :) @troy_s like to say "png is broken format" :) ... hard to say from given info ... try to resave png in another app or use different file format. Or share your sample file or texture to let us test it. I'm expecting you test it in a new default file setup.

Comment: Right on the nose it seems. I re-saved the img using windows photos (since ms.paint messes up the transparency. Now it looks like it is supposed to. Is there any mass-converter for <format> to png? (btw, I was unable to send a sample file since the model and textures are technically speaking copyright protected)

Comment: For batch conversion have a look here: https://superuser.com/questions/77429/using-gimp-to-batch-convert-images-to-another-format-in-windows